# Checkbox postback in Html.Grid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a grid which is by an IList:

```
@Html.Grid(Model.ExampleList).Columns(c =>
{
    c.For(a => string.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", a.DateRequested)).Named("Date Requested");
    c.For(a => a.Comment).Named("Comment");
})
```

But i'd like to add a checkbox which would Post back to a controller. Something similar to this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PostExample", "Home")) 
{
    <input type="hidden" name="SomeId" value=@ViewBag.SomeId/>
    <input type="hidden" name="AnotherId" value="AnotherId" />
    @Html.CheckBox("Complete", Model.Complete, new { onClick = "$(this).parent('form:first').submit();"
});
```

But I'm not sure how to combine them.  What is the best way of doing this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: confused! either you are me or both :p

Comment: Both possibly, lol.  I have changed the title (got posts mixed up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very unclear. Where do you want to show this checkbox? On each row? Dependent on some value of your model? If yes, then you could use a custom column, like this:

```
.Columns(c =>
{
    c.Custom(
        @<text>
            <form action="@Url.Action("PostExample", "Home")" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="SomeId" value="@ViewBag.SomeId" />
                <input type="hidden" name="AnotherId" value="AnotherId" />
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => item.Complete, new { onclick = "$(this).parent('form:first').submit();" })
            </form>
        </text>
    );
})
```

Comment: I apologize for the question begin unclear, but you assumed correctly, because that was exactly what I needed :).  Thank you so much for your help.